# Should "ankaŭ" stand before or after the concerned object? ("Mi ankaŭ" or "Ankaŭ mi"?)

Tags: word-usage

Imagine this discussion:

- "Kiel vi fartas?"
- "Bone"
- "Ankaŭ mi" / "Mi ankaŭ"

Is there a difference between "Ankaŭ mi" and "Mi ankaŭ"? Where should I put "ankaŭ"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe that *Mi ankaŭ* is wrong. However *ankaŭ* normally goes before the relevant word or phrase, and that is the habit to form.

The exceptions occur with *ki-* pronouns, e.g. *Kiu ankaŭ havas tiun problemon?* ("Who else has that problem?") and (very occasionally) with other pronouns for stylistic reasons: *Ĉu li ankaŭ troviĝis inter la amaso?* ("Was he, also, to be found among the crowd?") When reading those sentences aloud, you should stress the words *kiu ankaŭ* and *li ankaŭ* for the sake of clarity.

For more details, see [PMEG on *ankaŭ*](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/ceteraj/ankau.html).

Comment: Your answer is slightly misleading, since PMEG – as you linked – recommends to not (over)use putting *ankaŭ* after a pronoun (but not a *ki*-correlative) it relates to, lest it cause confusion.

Comment: I've edited my answer to clarify that. Thanks.